# Is the /Widths array of a PDF font object redundant information?

Tags: pdf, fonts

A refrence to pdf informs that a pdf dictionary to defined a font resource needs to contain a property `/Widhts` giving this information:

> (Required except for the standard 14 fonts; indirect reference
>   preferred) An array of ( LastChar − FirstChar + 1) widths, each
>   element being the glyph width for the character code that equals
>   FirstChar plus the array index. For character codes outside the range
>   FirstChar to LastChar , the value of MissingWidth from the
>   FontDescriptor entry for this font is used. The glyph widths are
>   measured in units in which 1000 units corresponds to 1 unit in text
>   space. **These widths must be consistent with the actual widths given in
>   the font program**. (See implementation note 61 in Appendix H.)

emphasis added.

What good is it to provide the widths **again** is they are obviously included in the font program?

Plainly: Can somebody confirm or reject wether the information one is supposed to provide here, the glyph width is blantantly redundant information, considering it is even mentioned to be contained in the font-program?

**Or do some font programs inlcude glyphs without specifying their widths?**
Is it because there are font programs that do not include the widths, or is this merely an execercise in patience, indented to complicate the generation of PDF files, hoping people then stick to Adobe software?

Are the `/Widths` entries required to test if a referenced font (being not embedded), is "correct" (i.e. the pdf viewer is supposed to check if the font-program wanted by the pdf, might be the one found on the platform, comparing the `/Widths`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Widths array is documented as being present so that application programs can determine the metrics of glyphs without being required to decode a font. This might be of use (for example) when drawing a selection box around text, or highlighting text in some manner.

See pages 393 and 394 of the PDF 1.7 specification:

> The width information for each glyph is stored both in the font
>   dictionary and in the font program itself. (The two sets of widths
>   must be identical; storing this information in the font dictionary,
>   although redundant, enables a consumer application to determine glyph positioning without having to look inside
>   the font program.)

I should also mention that there are **many** PDF producers which regard abusing the Widths array as a convenient way to alter the spacing of a font. Where the Widths of the Font array do not match the metrics of the glyphs in the font program, Acrobat uses the Widths array values (which is the implementation note in Appendix H referred to by the text you quoted). I also seem to recall that the latest version of the specification lifts the exception for the base 14 fonts, **all** fonts are supposed to have a /Widths array now.
We've got numerouus examples of PDF files where the metrics array do not match the Widths in the font program.

Note that the Preflight checker in Acrobat Pro, when checking for PDF/A compatibility, will throw an error if the Widths and metrics differ.

So while it is technically true that the /Widths array is redundant, because the same information can be retrieved from the font, it is convenient for some applications to have the informaiton in a more readily accessible form and if (as a PDF consumer) you hope to match the rendering from Acrobat, you need to use it.

Comment: Thank you for illustrating in this answer the background. Maybe I now feel a little less fooled, having to provide this seemingly redundant data, given that I enjoy the feeling of having made something available to the pdf consumer, even *more readily available* ;) It also is encouraging to know that in those cases I need accuracy but am not willing to do the sensible thing and include the font-program this `/Widths` thing will have my back. Adobe must have read the book on how to keep stuff simple.

Comment: Yes that's also a good point which I forgot to mention; when the font isn't embedded, and the consumer selects a subsittute, using the /Widths array ensures that the glyphs are drawn at the expected postions, even if the metrics of the subsitute font differ.